# Why does my Qt application appear different when using NoMachine

Tags: qt, ssh, nomachine-nx, nomachine

I built a UI in QtCreator and I am trying to run it remotely.  If I SSH into the machine with the application using -Y, the UI appears like it did in the designer window.  If I use NoMachine with the NX protocol, the UI renders differently - all of the line edit widgets are cut short, fonts are different, etc.  In my application, I am using set style according to the documentation found here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#setStyle

Is there a graphics setting in NoMachine that needs to be adjusted?  Or is there another cause, possibly related to the source code itself?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK There isn't a setting that you can adjust within NoMachine. Maybe NoMachine developers can tell you more. I've contacted them in the past and they've always been very helpful. You should try contacting them.